# Enterprise Architect Diagram Frame / Diagram Reference in mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, hyperlink, enterprise-architect

I am currently working on a Script in Enterprise Architect using some SQL queries where i am trying to get every diagram where no link refers to (any kind). I successfully got the hyperlinks from the t_object table with what i can work with, but i cannot find where does the database store the diagram frame and diagram references. If anyone knows the answer please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are stored in `t_object` where `Object_Type == 'UMLDiagram'`.

The renderings are found in `t_diagramobjects` with the usual element linkage.